# Renormalization in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I'm trying to understand renormalization in quantum field theory.

I looked up some renormalization schemes on the internet, for example nlab has an entry https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/renormalization mentioning many different renormalization schemes such as BPHZ, Epstein-Glaser, RG Flow, Stuckelburg-Petermann RG Flow etc.

My question is: what's the difference (connection) between these different renormalization techniques? Are they the same as those taught in standard QFT books such as Peskin and Schroeder? Which one is the most correct and modern one that I should use in practice?

Comment: There is no necessarily something *most correct* or *most modern* - rather, different problems may require different approaches.

Comment: Is there a general principle or something like that from which we can derive these renormalization schemes? Or do we try to come up with one in each situation then compare with experiments?

Comment: I do not quite get what you are asking, or even what your prior knowledge is on this topic. But since you ask what you should *"use in practice"*, it is probably helpful to choose your resources wisely. So maybe take a look at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nPOV and then reconsider whether or not you think that they are talking about practice. Don't get me wrong I am really interested in the underlying mathematics involved, but the stretch between the rigorous construction of perturbative QFTs and the calculations done to get predictions could not be wider (At least in the involved semantics).

Comment: The most important thing to understand at a conceptual level (in my opinion) is the Wilsonian renormalization group. Wilson completely revolutionized the understanding of renormalization and his insights are still the gold standard. The other methods you mention are just technical tweaks on this basic idea. If you are interested in practical calculations, it is also worth learning the diagrammatic counterterm methods in, eg, Peskin and Schroeder.